# How to read until a given character in Lua 5.1?

Tags: io, lua

Up to lua 2.4, there used to be an `readuntil` function that can read until the first occurence of a specified character; in 2.5 this is removed and you have to pass an appropriate pattern to `file:read` instead; and in 5.1 it seems that the available formatting option for `read` has been further reduced, and the patterns valid in version 2.5 are no longer available.

How do I read from an input stream until the first occurence of a given character, say TAB? Trying to write an enhanced REPL with tab-completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tab-completion you need to read input in raw mode, that is, without waiting for a newline. This cannot be done in ANSI C.

Try a curses binding for instance: https://github.com/rrthomas/luaposix.

Comment: Ah, it looks like the lua-posix in Fedora is a bit out of date and does not have ``curses`` support; I'll see if they can update it. Thanks!